# nodejs connecting to db only once

Tags: database, node.js, sqlite

I have a db.js file that has this line in the top to connect to the database.. i call this file to run queries from inside other js files:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db = new sqlite3.Database('./mydatabase');

db.serialize(function() {

db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM lorem", function(err, row) {

  console.log(row.id + ": " + row.info);

});


db.close();
```

If i require() this above file 4 times in different files, does this mean sqlite database will be initialized that many times?

I want to initalize it only the first time..

Is this inefficient? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: This question boggled me for a while. Cold answernig person also tell, whether in general each js file linked to main.js has to import the libraries it uses, or the requires happen in main.js and the child js files no longer need to re-require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Official documentation: https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/Caching

Sqlite3 module can do caching internally if you use `require('sqlite3').cached`, i.e. it won't create new connections on `new sqlite3.cached.Database(file)` as long as string held by `file` is identical, but reuse existing ones. See in the source for yourself here:
https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/blob/master/lib/sqlite3.js

However, you should not depend on that. Do some kind of dependency injection, it will save many headaches along the way. In simplest form it will be writing your modules that they export functions accepting database object as their argument:

```
//module1.js
module.exports = function(db){
    db.serialize(...)
    //dostuff
}

//start.js
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var module1 = require('./module1.js');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('./mydatabase');

module1(db);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work currently. db is undefined after being passed.